# Can I display a Datadog monitor's history on a dashboard?

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have a monitor based on a Datadog metric. When I visit the show page for the monitor, it shows me a really nice graph of the metric's history, plus an evaluation graph with the warning and alert ranges already there (see below).

What I'm wondering is whether there's a way to display this on a separate dashboard. This way, if the monitor is updated, my dashboard will be updated dynamically.

[image: screenshot of graph within monitor page]

Comment: The only way I can think to do this is add an iFrame widget to a Dashboard and point it to the Monitor page as the source URL, e.g. `https://app.datadoghq.com/monitors/123456789?view=spans#status-history`. But since the monitor page is not updated dynamically, you would still need to refresh the Dashboard to see the latest information.